# Change text in textview inside ViewPager2 on button click from Fragment

Tags: java, android

I have a fragment containing viewPager2 and a few buttons... ViewPager2 contains a textView whose text I want to change on button click(present inside fragment not viewPager2).

**Interface**

```
public interface IUpdateCursor {

    void cursorOn_nextWord();
    void cursorOn_nextLine();
    void cursorOn_nextTextBlock();

    void cursorOn_previousWord();
    void cursorOn_previousLine();
    void cursorOn_previousTextBlock();
}
```

**Fragment**

```
public class Read_fragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ImageButton imgbtn_back,imgbtn_left_top, imgbtn_right_top, imgbtn_left_down, imgbtn_right_down;
    private Button btn_done, btn_center_top, btn_center_down;
    private ViewPager2 viewPager;
    com.example.vision.HighlightedTextView textView;

    public Read_fragment() {
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_read, container, false);
        initViews(view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new ReadViewPagerAdapter(getContext()));
//        displayOCRText(getAllImages(Application_TEMP_DIR,
//                getFilenameFilter(new String[]{"jpeg"})));
    }

    private void initViews(@NonNull View view) {
        imgbtn_back = view.findViewById(R.id.imgbtn_back);
        imgbtn_left_top = view.findViewById(R.id.imgbtn_left_top);
        imgbtn_right_top = view.findViewById(R.id.imgbtn_right_top);
        imgbtn_left_down = view.findViewById(R.id.imgbtn_left_down);
        imgbtn_right_down = view.findViewById(R.id.imgbtn_right_down);
        btn_done = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_done);
        btn_center_top = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_center_top);
        btn_center_down = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_center_down);

        viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView5);

        imgbtn_back.setOnClickListener(this);
        imgbtn_left_top.setOnClickListener(this);
        imgbtn_right_top.setOnClickListener(this);
        imgbtn_left_down.setOnClickListener(this);
        imgbtn_right_down.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_done.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_center_top.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_center_down.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.imgbtn_back       :{/*go back to preview without saving changes.*/navigateTo(R.id.action_read_fragment_to_preview_fragment);}break;
            case R.id.imgbtn_left_top   :{      /*previous word or alphabet.*/ imgbtn_left_top_CLICK();       }break;
            case R.id.imgbtn_right_top  :{      /*next word or alphabet.*/ imgbtn_right_top_CLICK();       }break;
            case R.id.imgbtn_left_down  :{      /*next sentence or paragraph*/  imgbtn_left_down_CLICK(view);      }break;
            case R.id.imgbtn_right_down :{      /*previous sentence or paragraph*/  imgbtn_right_down_CLICK(view);      }break;
            case R.id.btn_done          :{      /*apply changes and go back to preview.*/        }break;
            case R.id.btn_center_top    :{      /*mark in on first click, mark out on second click, then show cut, copy paste options.*/        }break;
            case R.id.btn_center_down   :{      /*Read from cursor location to end of page.*/        }break;
        }
    }

    private void navigateTo(@IdRes int actionResId){
        final NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()), R.id.container);
        navController.navigate(actionResId);
    }

    private void imgbtn_left_top_CLICK(){
//        UpdateCursor.setUpdateCursor();
//        iUpdateCursor.updateCursor(false,true);
        IUpdateCursor iUpdateCursor = (IUpdateCursor) this.getContext();
        iUpdateCursor.cursorOn_previousWord();
    }

    private void imgbtn_right_top_CLICK(){
//        this.iUpdateCursor = (IUpdateCursor) viewPager.getRootView();
//        iUpdateCursor.updateCursor(true,true);

        IUpdateCursor iUpdateCursor = (IUpdateCursor) this.getContext();
        iUpdateCursor.cursorOn_nextWord();
    }

    private void imgbtn_left_down_CLICK(View view){
//        this.iUpdateCursor = (IUpdateCursor) view;
//        iUpdateCursor.updateCursor(false,false);
        IUpdateCursor iUpdateCursor = (IUpdateCursor) this;
        iUpdateCursor.cursorOn_previousLine();
    }

    private void imgbtn_right_down_CLICK(View view){
//        this.iUpdateCursor = (IUpdateCursor) view;
//        iUpdateCursor.updateCursor(true,false);
        IUpdateCursor iUpdateCursor = (IUpdateCursor) this;
        iUpdateCursor.cursorOn_nextLine();
    }
}
```

**ViewPager Adapter**

```
public class ReadViewPagerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ReadViewPagerAdapter.ViewHolder>  {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Vector<Bitmap> images;

    public ReadViewPagerAdapter(Context context) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.images = new Vector<>(5);
        this.images = getAllImages(Application_TEMP_DIR,
                getFilenameFilter(new String[]{"jpeg"}));

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ReadViewPagerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_view_pager_read, parent, false);
        return new ReadViewPagerAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ReadViewPagerAdapter.ViewHolder myHolder, int position) {
        //TODO: set image in imageView.
        Bitmap bitmap = images.get(position);
        new OCR(myHolder).displayOCRText(bitmap);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return images.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OCRcallbacks, IUpdateCursor{

        com.example.vision.HighlightedTextView textView;
        FirebaseVisionText OCRText;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        }

        @Override
        public void setText(FirebaseVisionText texts) {
            this.OCRText = texts;
            this.textView.setText(this.OCRText.getText());
            this.textView.setVisionText(texts);
        }


        @Override
        public void cursorOn_nextWord() {
            this.textView.cursorOn_nextWord();
        }

        @Override
        public void cursorOn_nextLine() {
            this.textView.cursorOn_nextLine();
        }

        @Override
        public void cursorOn_nextTextBlock() {
            this.textView.cursorOn_nextTextBlock();
        }

        @Override
        public void cursorOn_previousWord() {
            this.textView.cursorOn_previousWord();
        }

        @Override
        public void cursorOn_previousLine() {
            this.textView.cursorOn_previousLine();
        }

        @Override
        public void cursorOn_previousTextBlock() {
            this.textView.cursorOn_previousTextBlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Kindly help me. And if possible please give me an insight into interface implementation as listeners and callbacks and how does interface act as references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar issue.
I solve it by keeping a parentView pointer in my adapter and in adapter constructor i add a parameter named "parentView" (type: viewGroup) which set it.

So each time i need to have an access to parent button / another view i used:(and you can also add a click listener - i add an example below )

```
parentView.findViewById(R.id.Parent-View-Name);
```

in my adapter.

---

This is how it should work in your case:

**ADAPTER**

**Step 1**

```
 private ViewGroup parentView; // Add new Var
 // change/add new constracotr 
 public ReadViewPagerAdapter(Context context,ViewGroup parent) {
    this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    //******
    this.parentView = parent;
    //******
    this.images = new Vector<>(5);
    this.images = getAllImages(Application_TEMP_DIR,
            getFilenameFilter(new String[]{"jpeg"}));

}
```

**Step 2**
When ever you would like to find your button just use "parentView.findViewById"

```
(ImageButton)parentView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_button).setOnClickListener(v1 -> {// Put Here what ever you want to happen when click happen}
```

I hope i help :) let me know

Comment: But I wonder if it can be done using interfaces.

Comment: Hi happy that i helped :) about using interfaces. As much as i know interface is abstract class and has nothing to do with UI. Hope i help:)

Comment: Yeah. I know that. I wanted to know how referencing works in it like you put in reference of the view then we feed in the parameters of using that reference then it goes back to the place where its implementation exists and executes the method. If I am wrong please do correct me.

Comment: Hey Ben. Could I offer a couple of posting tips? (1) Technical writing is preferred here, so it is best to use words in full, rather than "plz" etc. (2) We would rather feedback on the quality of the question was kept in comments under the question - they are not of interest to most readers, so we try to keep them out of answers themselves. (3) We tend to trim "hope this helps" etc - it is a nice sentiment but rather redundant. (4) The personal pronoun "I" is always a capital letter in English. Thanks!